# MVVM Structure of UI specific logic

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

what I currently try to solve is a dynamic Menu and Toolbar, but
I have some problems in defining the project structure.

I use Prism 5, from the toolkit I use the regions, modularity,
mvvm things. As the IOC I use autofac.
For later purposes (Plugins) and for the modules I would like 
to have the option for inserting the Menuitems in code.

Currently my structre is like:

- Core.Infrastructure
- Core.Model
- Core.ViewModel
- UI.WPF
- UI.WPF.App (knows every other dll)

I don´t want UI specific things in Core.Infrastructure, because
maybe I want to change the UI Toolkit later und reuse this project.

But I also don´t want the UI things in the Model, so I think the best
place for this is the ViewModel project.

But later, I don´t want that 3rd party people have "access" to the viewmodel
project, so how would you solve this particular problem?

Where to define the contracts for UI logic? How would you structure
the whole project?

Regards,
Kevin